# How do I bind a different DataContext for my UserControl?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

So I have an application that's setup like this.
my MainView.xaml

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CardViewModel.Users}"
                          dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
                          dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"
                          dd:DragDrop.UseDefaultEffectDataTemplate="True">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <controls:UserCard/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            </ItemsControl>
```

And the ViewModel

```
class BaseViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public CardViewModel CardViewModel { get; set; } = new CardViewModel();
}
```

This works fine it displays two `UserCards` which is my UserControl in the ItemsControl which is exactly what it should be doing and it also binds the `Text` properties to what it needs to.

```
 <Grid Style="{StaticResource UserCardStyle}">
        <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Edit"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Remove"
                          Command="{Binding BaseViewModel.CardViewModel.command}"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Grid.ContextMenu>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>



        <Grid Width="75"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Column="0">
            <Ellipse Width="50"
                         Height="50"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         Margin="10">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Avatar}"/>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Column="1">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"

                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           Width="180"
                           VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           Margin="10"
                           FontFamily="Consolas"/>


            <TextBlock Width="100"
                           Height="20"
                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                           Margin="5"
                           Text="{Binding Name}"
                           FontFamily="Consolas"/>
            <TextBlock Width="100"
                           Height="20"
                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           Text="{Binding Id}"
                           FontFamily="Consolas"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

However I wanted to add a DataContext as you can see at the top but I have no idea how to bind the DataContext of the UserControl to something else so that I can create commands for the `ContextMenu MenuItems`

I did setup a RelayCommand that works on the ViewModel because I have the DataContext set properly there.

Right now the UserCard datacontext inherits from it's parent in the MainWindow view which makes it to where the DataContext for the properties are all from `User`

```
public class User : ObservableObject
    {
        public ImageSource Avatar { get; set; } 
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to be able to either create a ViewModel for that specific control and add commands to that or so that I can bind it to the `CardViewModel` and still display the data from the `Users` collection

```
public CardViewModel()
{
    /*
     * Commands
     */
    command = new RelayCommand(o => LoadImage(), o => true);
    AddUser = new RelayCommand(u => DisplayUserBuilder(), u => true);

    Users = new ObservableCollection<User>();

    Users.Add(new User
    {
        Name = "User",
        Description = "A description",
        Id = 0
    });
    Users.Add(new User
    {
        Name = "User1",
        Description = "Super nice description",
        Id = 1

    });
```

If I set the DataContext in the CodeBehind like this, the command works fine but then I can't see any text

```
public partial class UserCard : UserControl
    {
        public UserCard()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new BaseViewModel();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need something like this :

```
<Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Edit"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Remove"
                      Command="{Binding DataContext.CardViewModel.command, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MainView}}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Didn't really work, I am a bit confused about the binding for the Command, do I add `DataContext` to the binding? And shouldn't I replace `MainView` with `Window`?

Comment: Your view (of type MainView) has property DataContext on it by default. I believe the DataContext of your MainView is of type BaseViewModel, so the code above should work. Do you get any error?
It doesn't matter if you use here Window, or MainView.

Comment: You need to add reference in the file to your MainView class. Or you can use Window class.

Comment: I don't have a `MainView` class though, do you mean my `MainWindow` ?

Comment: Look at the first line of your question :) "So I have an application that's setup like this. my MainView.xaml"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187262/discussion-between-marcin-topolewski-and-mark-denom).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing, adding a reference to the ViewModel and then setting it.

```
<Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu >
                <ContextMenu.DataContext>
                    <dad:BaseViewModel/>
                </ContextMenu.DataContext>

                <MenuItem Header="Edit"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Remove"
                          Command="{Binding CardViewModel.command}"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Grid.ContextMenu>
```

If someone knows a "better" or "cleaner" way of doing the same thing please let me know since I am trying to develop as a developer, no pun intended.